# Docker: Filter containers by image, ignoring the tag, then the images

Tags: docker, containers

I need to remove a series of open containers which are derived from an image which I have tagged many times so I have plenty of versions around. I also have plenty of containers running (which remained hanging from various tests I did with the various versions of the container).

What are the commands to quickly erase all of them? (I.E based on image name or whatever)

I found that you can do

```
docker container stop $(docker container ls -aq --filter "ancestor=imagename")
```

But this doesn't work with the various tagged versions (like imagename:1.0, imagename:2.0)

so to get all of them I had to use

```
docker container stop $(docker container ls -aq --limit 30)
```

Which gets the container created up to 1 month ago.

Prune just cleaned a few of them.

I won't list every and all the commands I tried.

Please tell me what is the quickest and cleanest way to clean an image and all the successive tagged versions, and the relative containers which are running or exited related to them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use some linux magic? For example

```sh
docker ps | grep <image-name> | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs docker stop
```

Explanation:

- `docker ps` show running containers
- `grep <image-name>` search for image-name in the previous command output
- `awk '{ print $1 }'` take the first 'column' (in this case the container id)
- `xargs docker stop` feed the ids to docker stop

Similarly, you could just use other bash commands to delete the containers and remove the images:

```sh
docker ps -a | grep <image-name> | awk '{ print $1 }' | xargs docker container rm
```

```sh
docker image ls | grep <image-name> | awk '{ print $3 }' | xargs docker rmi
```

A little warning: grep is not specific to docker and will filter just based on the contents of the string so if your image name appears in the container names or anywhere else, then this method will stop/remove those containers as well!

Comment: Yeah, I could use that if I knew! Or better said, I already knew those, but I am not skilled enough to put it togheter. I will try and put it as an answer if it works for me! Thank youu

Comment: Do we have something similar on windows?